# Validating a text field containing a float is a valid percentage value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form text field that has a KeyUp event.   On KeyUp I'm ignoring anthing but numbers, the period, backspace, delete and cursor keys.  So, the only thing in the field can be a number or period.

I need to verify these things (number will become a % not over 100.00%):
-The text field string is a valid number (which should always be true unless someone puts two '.'s in).
-The text field string has a max of 2 decimal places
-If the text field string has a decimal point, it has something after (1 or 2 decimal places, not just a period at the end)
-The number is not larger than 100 (<= 100)

examples (what I need to verify):

```
 95 is true (valid, decimal places not required)

 95. is false (don't need a '.' with no decimal place after)

 95.0 is true

 95.00 is true

 95.000 is false (3 decimal places not valid) 100 is true

 101.01 is false (over 100)

 101 is false (over 100)
```

I've seen some things that do several pieces of that list, but I'm not smart enough to modify the regex to get exactly what I need. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some people will suggest regexes, but I think a small function is better suited for such a validation:

```
function validate(x) {
    var parts = x.split(".");
    if (typeof parts[1] == "string" && (parts[1].length == 0 || parts[1].length > 2))
        return false;
    var n = parseFloat(x);
    if (isNaN(n))
        return false;
    if (n < 0 || n > 100)
        return false;

    return true;
}

console.log(validate("95"));
console.log(validate("95."));
console.log(validate("95.0"));
console.log(validate("95.00"));
console.log(validate("95.000"));
console.log(validate("101.01"));
console.log(validate("101"));
```

[**Live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/9VLgC/)

Comment: Awesome, much appreciated.  :)    I found a flaw though.  Two periods returns true, like "90.1." will return true.  Maybe I could figure out out.  I guess you could put one more if statement in there checking for a count of more than 1 period (or something like that).

Comment: Played around and adding this is a last if clause worked:            if ((x.length - x.replace(/\./g, "").length) > 1)
             return false;

Comment: There's a bug. `console.log(validate("s10"))` return `false` but `console.log(validate("10s"))` return `true`. Thank you for example.

Answer (score 4):

try this expression: the 100% is a special case of a more generic pattern

```
var re = /^((0|[1-9]\d?)(\.\d{1,2})?|100(\.00?)?)$/;
```

explanation

`(0|[1-9]\d?)` allows numbers from 0 to 99

`(\.\d{1,2})?` allows a dot with 1 or 2 digits after

`|` otherwise

`100` accept 100

`(\.00?)?` with optional 0 or 00

Edit:

I tried this jsfiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/pCDVn/1/  and it's working... look at the console

Comment: Nice work bro! would it possible to accept a 99.9 or 99.97 or any decimal point? Please advice. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could limit the length of your field to 5, check that the value can be cast to a number, and then verify that the number is between 0 and 100.  You won't be able to enter 100.00, but why would you need to?

Also, [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/QMqeN/) a fiddle for testing.  One note, if you really care about validating "95." as false, you'll have to add extra validation for that.  However, I'd advise against this requirement, because it is still represents a valid percentage and won't affect the outcome of calculations.