# decimal masking

Tags: jquery, mask

i am using [jQuery masked input plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/).

I need to define a mask for the decimal number for percentage so that all following are valid inputs -

- 1
- 10
- 1.1
- 1.10
- 10.1
- 10.10
- 99.99
- 100

A percentage cannot be greater than 100 so 100.00 is valid but 100.01 is not.

```
$("#" + enum.WomenInSororitiesId).mask("9?9.99"); //valid till 99.99
```

With the above code, I am getting at least one number, but then for 1-9 with decimal, the user needs to input it as 01.00 or 02.00.

How can I rework this mask so that it can work for above case?

Thanks.

Comment: As @Grinn says, don't think it's possible. Here is a question with a answer that has working validation function for a percentage textfield: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579267/validating-a-text-field-containing-a-float-is-a-valid-percentage-value

Comment: If you put your solution as an answer, i am going to accepts. http://jsfiddle.net/pCDVn/1/ this is a good find. On the side note, i have tested masking with ?99.99 and it is turning 1.1 into 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use the masked input plugin for this.

You can use a validation function to validate a percentage field with decimal places as described in a number of answers to this question:

[Validating a text field containing a float is a valid percentage value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579267/validating-a-text-field-containing-a-float-is-a-valid-percentage-value)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't much of an answer, but it doesn't appear that you can. As a consolation prize, here's a little code to test your value to ensure it is numeric and < 100.

```
$("#" + enum.WomenInSororitiesId).change(function () {
    val = $(this).val();
    if(!$.isNumeric(val) || val-0 > 100) {
        alert("Something went horribly, horribly wrong.");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i am going with the solution that @mccannf pointed me to.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by declaring custom masking definitions that allow a character to be either a decimal point or a number.  For example:

```
$.mask.definitions['~']='[0-9|.]';
$("input.abcd").mask("9?~9");
```

This says that:

- First character must be a number
- Subsequent characters are optional
- Second character can be [0-9] or .
- Third character can be [0-9] but not . (this prevents weird inputs like "5.2.")

The one downside of this method is that if you use the following mask:

```
$.mask.definitions['~']='[0-9|.]';
$("input.abcd").mask("9?~~~9");
```

Then inputs like "5...2" are valid.

Comment: Don't know why someone downvoted this; it's exactly what I was looking for.  Seems if you can set up a regex for a single character, you can set it equal to a character that you can use in the mask.